# Chaincode for Developers Cli error terminal 3

Tags: docker, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to deploy chaincode using the chain code for developers tutorial "http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html". I was able to complete the steps till Terminal 2 but get an Error in the command "docker exec -it cli bash" for Terminal 3.

Output for Terminal 1:

> []Received message REGISTER from shim
>   peer         | 2017-08-22 23:29:26.025 UTC [chaincode] HandleMessage -> DEBU 1a9 []Fabric side Handling ChaincodeMessage of type: REGISTER in state created
>   peer         | 2017-08-22 23:29:26.025 UTC [chaincode] beforeRegisterEvent -> DEBU 1aa Received REGISTER in state created
>   peer         | 2017-08-22 23:29:26.025 UTC [chaincode] registerHandler -> DEBU 1ab registered handler complete for chaincode mycc:0
>   peer         | 2017-08-22 23:29:26.025 UTC [chaincode] beforeRegisterEvent -> DEBU 1ac Got REGISTER for chaincodeID = name:"mycc:0" , sending back REGISTERED
>   peer         | 2017-08-22 23:29:26.025 UTC [chaincode] notifyDuringStartup -> DEBU 1ad nothing to notify (dev mode ?)
>   peer         | 2017-08-22 23:29:26.025 UTC [chaincode] notifyDuringStartup -> DEBU 1ae sending READY
>   peer         | 2017-08-22 23:29:26.025 UTC [chaincode] processStream -> DEBU 1af []Move state message READY
>   peer         | 2017-08-22 23:29:26.025 UTC [chaincode] HandleMessage -> DEBU 1b0 []Fabric side Handling ChaincodeMessage of type: READY in state established
>   peer         | 2017-08-22 23:29:26.026 UTC [chaincode] enterReadyState -> DEBU 1b1 []Entered state ready
>   peer         | 2017-08-22 23:29:26.026 UTC [chaincode] notify -> DEBU 1b2 notifier Txid: does not exist
>   peer         | 2017-08-22 23:29:26.026 UTC [chaincode] processStream -> DEBU 1b3 []sending state message READY

Output for Terminal 2:

> CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer:7051 CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc:0 ./sacc
>   2017-08-22 23:29:26.020 UTC [shim] SetupChaincodeLogging -> INFO 001 Chaincode log level not provided; defaulting to: INFO
>   2017-08-22 23:29:26.020 UTC [shim] SetupChaincodeLogging -> INFO 002 Chaincode (build level: ) starting up ...

Output for Terminal 3:

> docker exec -it cli bash
>   Error response from daemon: Container 37efeab8d4930060c9de46d3bab9ab1ab034781be26b4a5176b80b54d6c1180b is not running

I couldn't find any resolution for this. Can anyone help me? I am using MacOS X.

I uncommented the line "command: /bin/bash -c './script.sh'" in the yaml file.

Output for docker ps after terminal 1:

> docker ps
>   CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
>   befcf58f4b59        hyperledger/fabric-ccenv     "/bin/bash -c 'sle..."   21 seconds ago      Up 20 seconds                                                        chaincode
>   3129dac3e13b        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start -..."   21 seconds ago      Up 20 seconds       0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer
>   56a92979e7cb        hyperledger/fabric-orderer   "orderer"                22 seconds ago      Up 21 seconds       0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer

Output for docker ps after terminal 2:

> docker ps
>   CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
>   befcf58f4b59        hyperledger/fabric-ccenv     "/bin/bash -c 'sle..."   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                                                         chaincode
>   3129dac3e13b        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start -..."   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer
>   56a92979e7cb        hyperledger/fabric-orderer   "orderer"                2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer

Cli Error while running .yaml file:

> Returning dummy reject all policy because Admins could not be found in /Application/Admins
>   orderer      | 2017-08-23 23:09:50.644 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 154 Returning policy Readers for evaluation
>   orderer      | 2017-08-23 23:09:50.644 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 155 Returning dummy reject all policy because Readers could not be found in /Application/Readers
>   orderer      | 2017-08-23 23:09:50.644 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 156 Returning policy Writers for evaluation
>   orderer      | 2017-08-23 23:09:50.645 UTC [policies] GetPolicy -> DEBU 157 Returning dummy reject all policy because Writers could not be found in /Application/Writers
>   orderer      | 2017-08-23 23:09:50.645 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 158 Adding to config map: [Groups] /Channel
>   orderer      | 2017-08-23 23:09:50.645 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 159 Adding to config map: [Groups] /Channel/Application
>   orderer      | 2017-08-23 23:09:50.645 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 15a Adding to config map: [Groups] /Channel/Application/SampleOrg
>   cli          | Error: Got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST
>   orderer      | 2017-08-23 23:09:50.645 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 15b Adding to config map: [Values] /Channel/Consortium
>   orderer      | 2017-08-23 23:09:50.645 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 15c Adding to config map: [Groups] /Channel
>   cli          | Usage:
>   cli          |   peer channel create [flags]
>   cli          | 
>   cli          | Flags:
>   orderer      | 2017-08-23 23:09:50.645 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 15d Adding to config map: [Groups] /Channel/Application
>   cli          |   -c, --channelID string   In case of a newChain command, the channel ID to create.
>   orderer      | 2017-08-23 23:09:50.645 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 15e Adding to config map: [Groups] /Channel/Application/SampleOrg
>   cli          |   -f, --file string        Configuration transaction file generated by a tool such as configtxgen for submitting to orderer
>   orderer      | 2017-08-23 23:09:50.646 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 15f Adding to config map: [Policy] /Channel/Application/Admins
>   cli          |   -t, --timeout int        Channel creation timeout (default 5)
>   cli          | 
>   cli          | Global Flags:
>   cli          |       --cafile string              Path to file containing PEM-encoded trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoint
>   cli          |       --logging-level string       Default logging level and overrides, see core.yaml for full syntax
>   cli          |   -o, --orderer string             Ordering service endpoint
>   orderer      | 2017-08-23 23:09:50.646 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 160 Adding to config map: [Policy] /Channel/Application/Writers
>   cli          |       --test.coverprofile string   Done (default "coverage.cov")
>   cli          |       --tls                        Use TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
>   cli          |   -v, --version                    Display current version of fabric peer server
>   cli          | 
>   orderer      | 2017-08-23 23:09:50.646 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 161 Adding to config map: [Policy] /Channel/Application/Readers
>   orderer      | 2017-08-23 23:09:50.646 UTC [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 162 Adding to config map: [Values] /Channel/Consortium
>   orderer      | 2017-08-23 23:09:50.646 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 163 Rejecting CONFIG_UPDATE because: Error authorizing update: Error validating DeltaSet: invalid mod_policy for element [Policy] /Channel/Application/Writers: mod_policy not set
>   orderer      | 2017-08-23 23:09:50.646 UTC [orderer/main] func1 -> DEBU 164 Closing Broadcast stream
>   orderer      | 2017-08-23 23:09:50.648 UTC [orderer/common/deliver] Handle -> WARN 165 Error reading from stream: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
>   orderer      | 2017-08-23 23:09:50.649 UTC [orderer/main] func1 -> DEBU 166 Closing Deliver stream

Comment: Looks like the cli container has stopped unexpectedly for some reason. 1) Can you please make sure that after you do the docker-compose, all containers are ok? i.e. `docker ps` should show the containers (including CLI) up and running.

Comment: Hi! I was able to solve this but I have error in the invoke command. Can you help me with that? I have updated my Question above with it. Thanks!

Comment: Good to know its solved, I would recommend putting an answer to your original question here by yourself and mark is at the selected answer.. Also I'd recommend creating a separate question for the new issue, this way all interested ones will be able to see the question and potentially you'll have a faster response.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by commenting out the line "command: /bin/bash -c './script.sh'" in the "fabric-samples/chaincode-docker-devmode/docker-compose-simple.yaml" file.

Comment: This actually disables the channel creation and joining the channel, which are needed to move on to invokes etc.

Comment: Then this brings me back to my original error for "docker exec -it cli bash" command.

Comment: Whats the output of `docker ps` after 1) doing the terminal 1 and 2) after doing terminal 2?

Comment: I have uncommented the line "command: /bin/bash -c './script.sh'" in the yaml file. and updated my question with docker ps outputs.

Comment: Your cli container unexpectedly exited for some reason (its not shown on the list of live containers via `docker ps`) there's something in the script.sh file that's probably causing the error. Can you try it with commenting the `/bin/bash -c script.sh` line again again and spinning up network again, and in a new terminal do a `docker exec -it cli bash` and run the commands from script.sh manually one by one?

Comment: Hi! I found the CLI error while running the "docker-compose -f docker-compose-simple.yaml up" . I hope this makes sense to you. I have updated the question with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd read how this https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5309 resolves, looks like the problem is with the *chaincode-docker-devmode*'s artifacts

p.s. just update the fabric to 1.0.2 and pull the new fabric-samples repo, start the new containers, voila!

best
nas

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the response. I completed this using another method. Thanks!