# Chaincode for Developers tutorial error while instantiate chaincode

Tags: docker, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

This is a follow-up question for "[Chaincode for Developers Cli error terminal 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45828567/chaincode-for-developers-cli-error-terminal-3)". I am doing Chaincode for Developers tutorial and I am getting the following error when I run the command `peer chaincode instantiate -n mycc -v 0 -c '{"Args":["a","10"]}' -C myc` on. terminal 3.

Output for command `peer chaincode instantiate -n mycc -v 0 -c '{"Args":["a","10"]}' -C myc`:

> Error: Error getting (myc) orderer endpoint: Error endorsing GetConfigBlock: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = chaincode error (status: 500, message: "GetConfigBlock" request failed authorization check for channel [myc]: [Failed to get policy manager for channel [myc]])

Output for the command:

```
peer chaincode install -p chaincodedev/chaincode/sacc -n mycc -v 0
```

> 2017-08-23 15:10:21.852 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
>   2017-08-23 15:10:21.852 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
>   2017-08-23 15:10:21.852 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
>   2017-08-23 15:10:21.852 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc
>   2017-08-23 15:10:21.904 UTC [golang-platform] getCodeFromFS -> DEBU 005 getCodeFromFS chaincodedev/chaincode/sacc
>   2017-08-23 15:10:22.080 UTC [golang-platform] func1 -> DEBU 006 Discarding GOROOT package fmt
>   2017-08-23 15:10:22.081 UTC [golang-platform] func1 -> DEBU 007 Discarding provided package github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim
>   2017-08-23 15:10:22.081 UTC [golang-platform] func1 -> DEBU 008 Discarding provided package github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer
>   2017-08-23 15:10:22.082 UTC [golang-platform] GetDeploymentPayload -> DEBU 009 done
>   2017-08-23 15:10:22.085 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 00a Sign: plaintext: 0AA3080A5B08031A0B08DEB5F6CC0510...DF65FC130000FFFFF65F638E00120000 
>   2017-08-23 15:10:22.085 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 00b Sign: digest: 00E981BB0FC2A7D32706156C0F2E1521E5B62F58E231787D87B2CB57CD10C3FA 
>   2017-08-23 15:10:22.089 UTC [chaincodeCmd] install -> DEBU 00c Installed remotely response: 
>   2017-08-23 15:10:22.089 UTC [main] main -> INFO 00d Exiting.....

I had to comment out the line

`command: /bin/bash -c './script.sh`

in the file "docker-compose-simple.yaml in order to run the command

`docker exec -it cli bash`.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can see a few problems which might the root cause for the error you described. First of all please note, that during instantiate command:

```
peer chaincode instantiate -n mycc -v 0 -c '{"Args":["a","10"]}' -C myc
```

you are not pointing to the ordering service, since instantiate is an endorsement transaction eventually it has to be submitted to the ordering service and therefore it should be something like this:

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o ordererEndpoint:7050 -n mycc -v 0 -c '{"Args":["a","10"]}' -C myc
```

Note that error you received gives you a hint, since it says that wasn't able to obtain configuration block:

> Error: Error getting (myc) orderer endpoint: Error endorsing GetConfigBlock: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = chaincode error (status: 500, message: "GetConfigBlock" request failed authorization check for channel [myc]: [Failed to get policy manager for channel [myc]])

Additionally please make sure that `myc` is existing channel and you have correctly created it beforehand. You can simply do:

```
peer channel list
```

to retrieve a list of channels peer was joined to.

Answer (score 0):

The script that you disabled had the commands for creating the channels and joining peer to the channel, which are pre-requisites for doing invokes with the chaincode.

Comment: Ok. But if I don't disable that then I cannot run "docker exec -it cli bash" for terminal 3 and it goes back to my original question "Chaincode for Developers Cli error terminal 3".

Comment: Have you created the artifacts manually (the genesis block, the transaction arifact...)?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the response. I completed this using another method. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, maybe you can create a new answer and write your solution there, and mark it as the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is caused by the version of image. You're using 1.0.1, and you should change to 1.0.0. Check that the version code is

```bash
sudo docker images
```

Comment: @PrashantDewan - if you can p[lease share what you did it will be helpful for others

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker toolbox on Windows7 to run developer tutorial the end-of-line  notation needs to be change to be unix compatible in the scripts.sh. You can use notepadd++ -> edit -> EOL Conversion -> select unix.